# How do I add the elements names to the results using a double for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, element

I am using a double for loop to get the home teams expected goals. The following wil give a list of 400 expected homegoals like for:

```
 1.11
 1.76
 1.98
 etc
```

Is it possible that it is shown:

```
Arsenal - Chelsea 1.11
etc.
etc.
```

Where Arsenal is 1 of 20 i's in clubs and Chelsea 1 of 20 e's in clubs2?

```
test = []
for i in clubs:
    for e in clubs2:
        test.append(poisson_model.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'team': i, 'opponent': e,
                                       'home':1},index=[1])))
```

Comment: yes, looping over a list will loop through all the lists elements? Not exactly sure what you're asking here

Comment: Oh yes it will give the 400 results like:
1.22
1.65
1.76
etc
But now i dont know for what matches the results are. So my question is if it could also show the elements in the list so i know for which match the results are

Answer (score 0):

You can append anything to the list.

Like a tuple

```
test.append((i, e, poisson_model.predict(pd.DataFrame(...))))
```